# To access value of Django custom model field (non primary BigAutoField) after save

Tags: django, django-models, autofield

I have Django custom field "BigAutoField" in one of my models. This is not a primary key. I am using uuid as my primary key. 
On insertion, everything is working fine. I am getting a new entry in mysql database with auto incremented value of this field. But the problem is after save the model instance is not able to fetch this field's value. (dot notation is not working). I have to again fetch the object instance to access its value.
Can anyone help me how to access the value without reloading?

---

```
class BigAutoField(models.PositiveIntegerField):
__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sequence_name = kwargs.pop('sequence_name', None)
    kwargs['blank'] = True
    kwargs['editable'] = False
    kwargs['null'] = False
    kwargs['unique'] = True
    super(BigAutoField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def db_type(self, connection):
    engine = settings.DATABASE_ENGINE
    if engine[-5:] == 'mysql':
        return 'bigint AUTO_INCREMENT'
    elif engine == 'oracle':
        return 'NUMBER(19)'
    elif engine[:8] == 'postgres':
        return 'bigserial'
    else:
        raise NotImplemented()

def get_internal_type(self):
    return 'BigAutoField'

def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    try:
        return long(value)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                _("This value must be a long integer."))

def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection=None, prepared=False):
    if value is None:
        return value
    return long(value)
```

This is my custom bigautofield class. First time i perform a save on a model using this field it works fine.eg.

```
    x= XYZ.objects.create(a='a',b='b')
    x.save()
```

But now I am not able to access x.c where c is BigAutoField in XYZ. Though in mysql database an autoincremented value for the same is visible.

Comment: Add some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: What means: "not able to fetch this field's value. (dot notation is not working)." ? An error occurs? Field contains None?

Comment: @danihp: yes the field value remains blank. But I am able to access it if I reload the object again.

Comment: 'IDENTITY' or 'auto_increment' value is set on database, if for this reason that you can not read value on python object. After save you/django should read from database the assigned number: as you know is database engine who assigns value. Perhpas BigAutoField should innherit from AutoField instead from PositiveIntegerField.

Answer (score 0):

I had a special requirement of having uuid as primary key and 1 field as autofield in table. since django doesnt allow an autofield without being a primary key I had to inherit it from positive integer field.To solve this issue i had to implement a pre save function. This would fetch the next auto increment key from mysql db and set the attributes value before insertion. By this way my values are now getting saved properly and I am able access them as well.

```
 def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    if self.sequence_name is None:
        self.sequence_name = '%s' % (model_instance._meta.db_table)
    old_val = getattr(model_instance, self.attname)
    if add and old_val is None:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'knowlus' AND TABLE_NAME = %s", [unicode(self.sequence_name)])
        val = long(cursor.fetchone()[0])
        discard = cursor.fetchall()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, val)
        return val
    else:
        return long(old_val)
```